# Apache Camel - Quartz2 with mybatis using onConsume

Tags: apache-camel

My Camel:

```
<from uri="quartz2://processTimers?cron=5+*+*+*+*+*" />
<to uri="mybatis:selectProducts?statementType=SelectList&amp;onConsume=consumeProduct"/>
<bean ref="productService" method="process" />
<to uri="mq:queue:my.queue"/>
```

When using a Quartz from, the selectProducts returns the expected results but the onConsume for some doesnt execute at the end, I suspect this is because its a "to" and not a "from" method.

Is there anyway to have a cron scheduled mybatis select with an onConsume?

Updated:

```
<from uri="mybatis:selectProducts?statementType=SelectList&amp;onConsume=markProductAsExtracted&amp;maxMessagesPerPoll={{MAX_RECORDS_PER_PROCESS}}&amp;scheduler=quartz2&amp;scheduler.cron=5+*+*+*+*+?"/>
<bean ref="productService" method="process" />
<to uri="mq:queue:my.queue"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes see the scheduled polling consumer: http://camel.apache.org/polling-consumer.html

You can specify on the mybatis endpoint that the scheduler is cron and then setup the cron value as well. See that doc for more details.

Also I wrote a little blog once: http://www.davsclaus.com/2013/08/apache-camel-212-even-easier-cron.html its about the file component but its the same for mybatis.

Comment: Ok this works but the behaviour i want is for a cron to run once per day, then mybatis polls for X amount of messages, if there are more than the X of messages, it keeps pulling messages until there are no more. 
Seems like wht you've suggested just runs the cron once per poll, not once for many polls.